# Generalization of the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac 1 i$ is not an integer for all $n>1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Its a generalization I thought for the following problem :-
Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac 1 i$ is not an integer for all $n>1$.

**Conjecture**-For any non-constant arithmetic progression $a,a+d,a+2d,...,a+(n-1)d$ with $(a,d)=1$, none of the $2^n$ sums $$\pm\frac{1}{a}\pm\frac{1}{a+d}\pm\frac{1}{a+2d}\pm...\pm\frac{1}{a+(n-1)d}$$ is an integer.

Here is what I think:
*If there exists a prime* $p$ such that $p^k|a+id$ for some $i\in\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ and no higher power of $p$ will divide any other term. Let $l=[a,a+d,...,a+(n-1)d]$. We assume that $$\pm\frac{1}{a}\pm\frac{1}{a+d}\pm\frac{1}{a+2d}\pm...\pm\frac{1}{a+(n-1)d}=x$$ where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $$lx=\pm\frac{l}{a}\pm\frac{l}{a+d}...\pm\frac{l}{a+id}\pm...\pm\frac{l}{a+(n-1)d}$$. RHS will be divisible by $p$ iff $p|\frac{l}{a+id}$ which is not true, thus our assumption was wrong.

As per the comment below my mistake was in assuming that only $a+id$ is divisible by $p^k$. Well I think the conjecture can be proved if I can show that for any such AP there exists a prime $p$ such that $p^k$ is the highest power of it such that it divides only one of the terms.
Can this statement be proved or disproved?

Does there exists any counterexamples?

Comment: the mistake commes from assumming only $a+id$ is divisible by $p^k$

Comment: It is incomplete. The sum $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}$ is a counterexample to the **technique**, though not to the assertion since there are missing terms.

Comment: @Carry on smiling, is there a way to save the argument?

Comment: I'm not sure. I really like your conjecture though, I'll be sure to get back to you. By the way, why do you ask that $a$ and $d$ be coprime? I think that the case in which they are coprime can be used to prove the other case trivially.

Comment: I thought of disposing any common divisors of the terms of the AP, no particular thought though.